Cosmos DB duplicate children are null
I have a HotelConference object that has a collection of Events.
Each Event has an EventLocation.
Events can have the same location as two events might be held in BallRoomA.
When I add an Event with a EventLocation that has already been assigned to a previous Event, the first Event.EventLocation is null.
Here are the libs I am using
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="9.0.0-preview.6.24328.4" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos" Version="9.0.0-preview.6.24327.4" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="9.0.0-preview.6.24327.4">


Here are the classes
public class Conference : CosmosBase
{
    public Hotel Hotel { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Event> Events { get; set; } = new List<Event>();
    public string ConferenceName { get; set; }
}
public class Event : CosmosBase
{
    public Conference Conference { get; set; }
    public EventLocation EventLocation { get; set; }
    public string EventName { get; set; }
}
public class EventLocation : CosmosBase
{
    public Hotel Hotel { get; set; }
    public string EventLocationName { get; set; }
}


Here is the Seeding Code
List<Event> CreateEvents(Hotel h, Conference c, List<EventLocation> locs)
{
    var e0 = new Event();
    e0.PK = h.PK;
    e0.ID = e0.GetNewID();
    e0.Conference = c;
    e0.EventName = "Conference Check In";
    e0.EventLocation = locs[0];

    var e1 = new Event();
    e1.PK = h.PK;
    e1.ID = e1.GetNewID();
    e1.Conference = c;
    e1.EventName = "Keynote Session";
    e1.EventLocation = locs[0];

    var events = new List<Event>();
    events.Add(e0);
    events.Add(e1);
    return events;
}


event e0.EventLocation is null.
The eventlocation obviously has the same id, but that should not be a problem, but I suspect it is.
Here is the resulting json in Cosmos db
{
    "ID": "2516807109275195800",
    "PK": "H-0d5fdf24-845b-4d0b-b92b-1e48979f69aa",
    "ConferenceDescription": "All hotels conference",
    "ConferenceEndDate": "2024-10-10T15:00:00-05:00",
    "ConferenceName": "The Big Conference",
    "ConferenceStartDate": "2024-10-07T09:30:00-05:00",
    "Discriminator": "Conference",
    "HotelID": "2516807109275205674",
    "HotelPK": "H-0d5fdf24-845b-4d0b-b92b-1e48979f69aa",
    "id": "Conference|2516807109275195800",
    "Events": [
        {
            "ID": "2516807109275185830",
            "EventDescription": "Check in to conference",
            "EventEndDate": "2024-10-07T15:30:00-05:00",
            "EventName": "Conference Check In",
            "EventStartDate": "2024-10-07T06:00:00-05:00",
            "PK": "H-0d5fdf24-845b-4d0b-b92b-1e48979f69aa",
            "EventLocation": null
        },
        {
            "ID": "2516807109275183758",
            "EventDescription": "Where the keynote speakers talk",
            "EventEndDate": "2024-10-07T10:30:00-05:00",
            "EventName": "Keynote Session",
            "EventStartDate": "2024-10-07T09:00:00-05:00",
            "PK": "H-0d5fdf24-845b-4d0b-b92b-1e48979f69aa",
            "EventLocation": {
                "EventLocationDescription": "The biggest ballroom we have",
                "EventLocationName": "Grand Ballroom",
                "HotelID": "2516807109275205674",
                "HotelPK": "H-0d5fdf24-845b-4d0b-b92b-1e48979f69aa",
                "ID": "2516807109275190703",
                "PK": "H-0d5fdf24-845b-4d0b-b92b-1e48979f69aa"
            }
        },


I think you have something set up incorrectly in your schema where it may treating the relationship between event and event location as a one to one rather than a many-to-one. I do not see an EventLocationId referenced in your Event table which would be needed for a many-to-one allowing events to share a location. If instead the schema is putting an EventId on your EventLocation then the location would just end up on the last event you associated it with.
Also, what is the significance of the PK column vs the ID column? That looks rather confusing as both events and the Event Location share the same "PK" value. "PK" typically is inferred as meaning "Primary Key" which is synonymous with an "ID" column, usually marked as the PK.

Thank you Steve for posting.  The current dbcontext is using one dbset for Conference so all children are included in the conference.
The fact that I am adding a EventLocation to the ConferenceEvent puts a ConferenceEvent.EventLocationID on in the db.
Except in this case of one dbset.

When I run it with a dbContext with 5 dbsets so all data is in seperate objects in cossmos the Event (now ConferenceEvent) has the EventLocationID.
{
"ID": "251..
"PK": "H-7bb..
"ConferenceID": "251..
"ConferencePK": "H-7bb..
"EventLocationID": "251680..
"EventLocationPK": "H-7bbae3..
"id": "Event|251..
...
}
Is this a bug in EF Core?

As far as the PartitonKey goes, I am coming from a TableStorage background.
My desire is for all objects to have a PartitonKey so the queries are faster.
Each Hotel will have a PartitonKey, so all children should live in the same partition.
My understanding is that the ID on an object translates into the RowKey.  Toughts?

It looks like the issue is that ultimately CosmosDB expects to behave as a NoSQL solution so the ORM capabilities for EF will have some limitations. I see the EF tag and assume relational DB as it's an ORM, vs. wrappers for NoSQL document stores. Where in a relational database the EventLocation would be a single row in a table and referenced by the other table rows, with NoSQL it would need to be a distinct reference for each reference under the applicable events. Passing a single reference likely just "moves" the item from one document to the other.

Instead of setting both to EventLocations[0] you likely will need to clone the event location into a separate instance to add to each Event.

When I do a deepclone with json ser/des  I am getting Hotel trouble.  As every EventLocation belongs to a Hotel.  Self referencing loop detected for property 'Hotel.  Thanks for your help,  Will check back tomorrow after work.

fyi comments are not intended to be used as an extended discussion area. Please keep comments limited to clarification questions. @Terrence - it's better to edit your question, rather than posting code or data in comments.

@DavidMakogon  Got it.  Thanks.
